# How to upload an image in "read only" input field

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to upload an image in a read only input field. The code below works, but takes image url as a text file.

FYI - swf_creative is pointing to the config file where the url image is saved. The url is:
 swf_creative=/Testing/creatives/Contemp.swf

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('fileName').value=\"" + swf_creative +"\"");
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question little bit more?

Comment: Hey Saifur, if you may recall what you suggested in the morning regarding the code above. It works, i.e. I am able to enter file into the input field. But I want to add an image into the input field, because that is the purpose of this input field(in that case, it is swf file) Currently, when the script clicks on the upload button, after adding the url into the input field, it acts like that it is performing the desired functionality, but there is nothing in the input field. Test does not fail either...I am attaching a screenshot of the fields above. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I do. I think the input control is hidden and thus, you don't see it. Looking at the screenshot I think you can send keys on Flash File and hit Upload. Will that upload the file or not?

Comment: sendkey does not work... I tired, it does not recognize the element

Comment: Do you know why not?

Comment: because the input field is read only...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71219/discussion-between-saifur-and-familyguy).

Comment: After having a detailed discussion with Saifur, this worked.... driver.findElement(By.name("theFile")).sendKeys("/Testing/creatives/Contemp.swf"); driver.findElement(By.id("btnCreativeHostingFileUpload")).click();